# How to implement Remarketing with Universal Analytics through Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've followed these 5 steps: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6166257?hl=en#DR

1: Added the necessary attributes to my dataLayer

```
dataLayer.push({
    'ecomm_prodid': 'XXXXXX',
    'ecomm_pagetype': 'product',
    'ecomm_totalvalue': 0.99
});
```

2: Created new Custom Dimensions in the admin interface of Google Analytics

[image]

3: Setup Dynamic Attribute Linking in Google Analytics

[image]

4: Created three new user-defined variables in Google Tag Manager

[image]

5: Added the new user-defined variables I created in Tag Manager to my Universal Analytics tag

[image]

Google Tag Manager is published but I'm still getting wrong/unreplaced Custom Parameters in Google Tag Assistant (Chrome):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a custom HTML tag which was the wrong place to look for. I've deleted/disabled it and looked at the Analytics tag which shows the correct custom dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

There might be something wrong in data layers obtaining values, does the preview mode show the datalayer variables correctly ?

If everything is correctly setup,

1. Try changing the data layer position in the code too, it should be above container snippet normally.
2. Delay the tags firing to- "DOM Ready" or "Page Load" (before doing this check if datalayers are loading at these parts)